# I have two google ads on my website, the first one will only show if the second one is there

Tags: javascript, css, adsense

I have placed a google ad at the top of my website and on the left-hand sidebar on the main home page.

I try removing the left-hand sidebar, but when I do the top advertisement does not show up...

I have been looking at the code to try and see if there are differences or something I am missing from the first ad code but I can not find anything and I can not explain why it will not show up unless I have the 2nd left-hand side add there.

The top of the page ad I am having issues with showing up looks like this:

```
<div align="center">
<style type="text/css">
.adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media (min-width:500px) { .adslot_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
    style="display:inline-block;"
    data-ad-client="myGoogleID"
    data-ad-slot="adID"></ins>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
</div>
```

Then the code for the ad that always shows up on the left-hand side looks like this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Seek Adventure In Post Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="myGoogleID"
     data-ad-slot="differentAdID"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

If you want to see both of them displayed you can go to the homepage [here](https://www.seekadventure.net/).

Then if you go directly to one of my subpages like [this one](https://www.seekadventure.net/d/108-partington-cove-trail-julia-pfeiffer-burns-state-park-big-sur). The ad will not show up because the left-hand ad is not on my subpage.

Comment: Looks like the opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095912/how-do-you-use-multiple-adsense-units-on-one-page but that may help someone find an answer

Comment: Is the problem not related to the fact that the site is very heavy? Over 118MB! Try deleting photos and displaying only the ad.

Comment: i know its a bit old, but the only the top ad loads on the home page for me, did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: Still trying to resolve..

Answer (score 4):

Too big for comment:

At first I had the same result as @AlexanderHolman comment on Firefox 67.0.4 I only see the top advert. I had to disable content blocker in FF and the adblocker plugins, so maybe you are experiencing something similar.

But then I think I noticed something that could point you to the right direction: 
when on home page an extra `<ins>` and `<iframe>` tags are appended at the end of the  which means that you are implementing some special logic for the home page.
I also notice that there is a difference between a direct navigation to a discussion and a navigation from home page: 
have a look at:

```
//Direct navigation
<div id="app" class="App affix App--discussion">

//Navigate from home page
<div id="app" class="App affix hasPane App--discussion" style="">
```

So I haven't went through the page code  (there is a lot) but hope this will navigate you to the correct answer.

p.s. The Javascript code is not minified and probably not [tree shaken](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking/)

Answer (score 1):

*As I don't have to full code of your site it will take some Q/A sessions to evaluate your answer*

Please perform the following step-

1. Change `style="display:inline-block` to `style="display:block` for the first Ad style and check if your problem is solved